# Xrandr gone crazy with dual monitor setup

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amdgpu

I have a dual monitor setup, on a dual boot computer with Windows 7 and Lubuntu 18.04. This has been working fine the past few months, when I first bought a new second monitor (a Viewsonic XG2401). My old monitor has become my secondary monitor, on my left, with a resolution of 1680x1050 via a DVI port, and the new monitor I keep as primary with a resolution of 1920x1050 via a DisplayPort.

Tonight I booted Windows 7 to play games with friends. Upon rebooting to Lubuntu, both monitors were at an incredibly low resolution, and mirrored. With `arandr` I could set them in their original location, but while I could reset my old monitor to its own resolution, the ViewSonic max available resolution was 1024x768.

In Windows the two monitors work fine, just as before. I played around with xrandr, re-adding a 1920x1050 mode to the monitor, but as soon as I rebooted, that was lost, and every time I was back to two low-res mirrored monitors.

Then I uninstalled my graphics drivers. My card is a `HD7770-1GD5`, so I'm not even sure exactly which drivers I'm supposed to have at this point, since the Asus driver page does not list that (it lists a HD7770 Ghz edition). Uninstalling the graphics drivers results in my ViewSonic monitor, via DisplayPort, to stop working, but the other one worked just fine.

I reistalled the drivers of the HD7770 Ghz edition. At first reboot, the monitors were fine, with the four low-res modes plus the new mode I had manually added to the monitor. At the second reboot, the ViewSonic magically recovered all its original settings and modes and intermediate possible resolutions, and everything worked as it was before. At its third reboot, I am back at square one, with two mirrored monitors at low res at boot.

GRUB seems to "feel" these changes, as the times it worked it used to appear on my main monitor; now it only appears on my old, secondary monitor, and leaves the main one blank (sometimes it appears in both, but it seems random now).

I'd like to make it work as before, and I have literally no idea what to think. This is the first time something like this has ever happened to me.